# Dating simulator anime?

Tags: the-world-god-only-knows

Can someone help me identify the name of this anime with a dating simulator involved?

The plot goes like this:
A kid in highschool is into dating simulators on his PSP. Demon's from hell comes to collect demons from girls that have shut in their emotions and he is the only one to help the demon by making those girls fall in love with him.

Does anyone know the name of this anime?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [Kami nomi zo Shiru Sekai](http://myanimelist.net/anime/8525/Kami_nomi_zo_Shiru_Sekai)

Also known as [The World God Only Knows](http://myanimelist.net/anime/8525/Kami_nomi_zo_Shiru_Sekai)

[image: cover]

## Synopsis

> Keima is a dating sim champion. Cute girls are rendered powerless by his irresistible game playing techniques. Too bad things aren't that way in the real world. That is, until his tempting game playing causes a real live—and very bubbly-cute—demon hunter named Elsie to materialize! Now Elsie wants Keima to help her free hot girls from sneaky demons who secretly possess them.

Source: Sentai Filmworks